# segmentation in group in cq5.4

Tags: aem

In CQ5.4 is there a way to add group in properties of segmentation ,so that  a particular teaser is available to be viewed by  the selected group only.After applying segmentation, teaser should be viewed only to certain people which are inside that group.Security of page is done for the group but how the group segmentation will be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you request all subpages/Nodes (assuming you don't use admin sessions) then you get only the pages that are accessible to you.

Now you could do the same thing for teasers. Set a group policy on a teaser. Now if you request all available teaser nodes you only get the ones that apply to you.